# Button.setEnabled(false) does not make the button grey

Tags: android, android-button

I have a `Button` in my application. When I use `setEnabled(false)` on it, it turns grey. However if I first modify the background of the `Button` and then call `setEnabled(false)` on it, it does not turn grey (but the `Button` is not enabled). Why is that and how can I make it grey whatever happens to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that

Usually, the background for a `Button` is a `ColorStateList`: specific colors are assigned to different states like "enabled" or "disabled" (possible states depend on the type of widget). If the state changes, the runtime changes the color of the background accordingly.

You provided a single color as the `Button`'s background, so it will be used no matter what the current state of the `Button` is.

> and how can I make it grey whatever happens to it?

Create a drawable resource containing a `ColorStateList` (following for example this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource)) and use it as the background drawable.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the easiest solution would be to set the background of the button in your activity. Like the following:

```
button.setAlpha(.5f);
button.setClickable(false);
```

.5f alpha is equivalent to grey disable button. It's often useful if the background of your button is an image.

Answer (score 2):

there are a couple of decisions for your issue:
The easiest: to change the background of the button. 
Or you can use selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="#9e9e9e"
        />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="#56934d"
        />
</selector>
```